# Why isn't my list of users being displayed?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

When clicking the "Add User" button the username and password is added to an array.  This should display on a `<ul>` element.  The data is in the array, for some reason it won't output to the page.  Looks to me like this should work.

Any idea why?  [Here is my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6cxhx3?file=src/Users/UsersList.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you don't `return` the `li` in `map` block.

You can fix it by adding `return`:

```js
const UsersList = props => {
  return (
    <Card className={classes.users}>
      <ul>
        <li>1st element</li>
        {props.users.map((user, ndx) => {
          console.log(user);
          return (
            <li key={ndx}>
              {user.username} - {user.password}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

**Note:** try always to add [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) when looping on the array using `map`, I added the index here as key, but it's better to be the `id` of the user or another `unique` property, because:

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
> removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
> the elements a stable identity

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it would be something simple!

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning React, it lakes parenthesis (on multiline)

```
import React from 'react';

import Card from '../UI/Card';
import classes from './UsersList.module.css';

const UsersList = props => {
  return (
    <Card className={classes.users}>
      <ul>
        <li>1st element</li>
        {props.users.map(user => {
          return (
          <li>
            {user.username} - {user.password}
          </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default UsersList;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because in your UserList.js you are not returning the `<li>` from the map function.

```
const UsersList = props => {
  return (
    <Card className={classes.users}>
      <ul>
        <li>1st element</li>
        {props.users.map(user => {
          console.log(user);
          return (
            <li>
              {user.username} - {user.password}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </Card>
  );
};
```